# Cumulative values of a column for each group (R)

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this :

```
> year<-c(2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016)
> group<-c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
> n<-c(1,1,1,1,2,0,2,1,1)
> df<-data.frame(year=year,group=group,n=n)
> df

year group n
2014     A 1
2014     B 1
2014     C 1
2015     A 1
2015     B 2
2015     C 0
2016     A 2
2016     B 1
2016     C 1
```

I want to create a column that contains the cumulated values of n for each group to have something like this :

```
year group n  sum
2014     A 1  1
2014     B 1  1
2014     C 1  1
2015     A 1  2
2015     B 2  3
2015     C 0  1
2016     A 2  4
2016     B 1  4
2016     C 1  2
```

Comment: `transform(df, sum = ave(n, group, FUN = cumsum))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use one of the group by functions.  With `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, group by 'group', we assign (`:=`) the `cumsum(n)` as the "Sum" column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Sum:= cumsum(n),group]
```

Or with `base R`, we can do this with `ave`.

```
 df1$Sum <- with(df1, ave(n, group, FUN=cumsum))
```